# Add padding to a titlewindow in Flex 4 (ideally using skins)?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

By default TitleWindows seem to have no padding. I tried the properties "left", "right" etc and it doesn't work. Actually I'd like to have a default for my whole app, so I tried creating a skin but no matter where in the skin I add 'left="50"' it just doesn't create padding on the left. You'd think that you should add it to the element with id="contentGroup", as described on this [Adobe Skinning help page](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS422719A4-7849-4921-AF39-57FF567B483B.html), but that does not work.

Surely this is something almost everyone wants to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The contentGroup in the default TitleWindowSkin is inside a VerticalLayout which does not respect top/left/right/bottom constraints.

You could do this by duplicating the default TitleWindowSkin and wrapping the contentGroup with a Group with width/height of 100%:

```
...
<s:Group width="100%" height="100%">
    <!--- @copy spark.components.SkinnableContainer#contentGroup -->
    <s:Group id="contentGroup" top="10" left="10" right="10" bottom="10" minWidth="0" minHeight="0" />
</s:Group>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the `TitleWindow` extends the `Panel` component, it doesn't support the padding properties a `HGroup` or `VGroup` based component would. As far as I know, there's no way to skin a `TitleWindow` so that the padding properties are automatically set.

All I do is set the `x` and `y` coordinates of my components within the `TitleWindow` so that they are laid out where I want them.